# Handling error thrown by resource controller's method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I' working with `Laravel 5.6` and i've decided to create a resource controller to handle one of my models. Right know im trying to destroy a record from the database like this:

```
public function destroy(Role $role)
  {
      $role->delete();

      return response([
          'alert' => [
              'type' => 'success',
              'title' => 'Role destroyed!'
          ]
      ], 200);
  }
```

It works just fine as longs as the `$role` exists. My problem is that i want to handle the response myself in the case that `$role` does not exist to do something like this:

```
return response([
     'alert' => [
         'type' => 'ups!',
         'title' => 'There is no role with the provided id!'
     ]
], 400);
```

But instead, i'm getting a error like this:

`"No query results for model [App\\Models\\Role]."`

And that is something I don't want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: then you can't typehint `Role` because if it doesn't exist, it fails the type check for the methods parameters

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the `Role` doesn't exist won't it just produce a 404?

Comment: So, should i work like this: ``destroy(Request $request, $role_id){...}`` ?

Comment: Are you making the request with ajax or just a standard form?

Comment: I'm sending a ``object``. The function itself works fine, it does what's expected. I want to know if i can handle the error inside the function itself, ergo, return an response with a status code 404

Comment: Sending an `object`, does that mean you're making an ajax request i.e. sending it with javascript rather than a traditional form?? Sorry, I wasn't trying to suggest that there is anything wrong with how you're making the request. As I mentioned in my comment before, it should return a 404 status code automatically if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get what you were saying. Yes, i am sending it with javascript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"No query results for model [App\\Models\\Role]."` is the standard response message for a `ModelNotFound` exception in Laravel.

The best way to change the response for an exception like this is to use the exception handler's render function to respond with whatever message you want.

For example you could do

```
if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $response['type'] = "ups!;
        $response['message'] = "Could not find what you're looking for";
        $response['status'] = Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND
    }


    return response()->json(['alert' => $response], $response['status']);
```

The alternative is to ensure that the `ModelNotFound` exception does not get thrown (So use `->find()` rather than `->findOrFail()` when querying the model)
and then using the abort helper like so if no results are returned:

```
abort(400, 'Role not found');
```

or

```
return response(['alert' => [
    'type' => 'ups!', 
    'title' => 'There is no role with the provided id!']
],400);
```